# lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c

I am not able to compile this program.can anyone tell me tell me where i am going wrong.

```
int i = 8, j, k;
++i = ++j = ++k = 8;
printf("\n %d \t %d \t %d",i,j,k);
```

it is giving the error 
`error : lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

Comment: What do you expect `++i = 8` do do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what has already been said, you should not try to deliberately obfuscate your code. You have managed to do this to the point where you don't understand your own code. It would have been much better programming practice to write:

```
int i = 8;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;

++i;
++j;
++k;

i = 8;
j = 8;
k = 8;

printf("\n %d \t %d \t %d", i, j, k);
```

Now when we fixed the coding style to use declarations on separate lines, it becomes clear that j and k were not initialized. I fixed that bug above.

Comment: I don't think you should pick this as the answer, since it was rather posted as an addendum to the others. All the 3 other answers are correct and point out the reason why the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

The segment `++i` is not an lvalue (so named because they generally can appear on the left side of an assignment).

As the standard states (`C11 6.3.2.1`):

> An lvalue is an expression (with an object type other than void) that potentially designates an object.

`i` itself is an lvalue, but pre-incrementing it like that means it ceases to be so, `++i` is an expression not representing any particular object.

Comment: Explaining a bit further, `++i` is defined as `i += 1`, and assignment operators are defined as not yielding an lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

"Lvalue required" means you cannot assign a value to something that has no place in memory. Basically you need a variable to be able to assign a value.
in this case your variable having ++operator that acts as both a statement and an assignment

Answer (score 0):

```
++i = ++j = ++k = 8;
```

is not valid. The ++ operator acts as both a statement and an assignment, and hence you cannot assign it and provide a value on the right hand side. You can do

```
i = j = k = 8;
```

or

```
i++; j++; k++;
```

both of which have very different meanings. It looks like you are probably looking to do the first one, since you never assign j or k and incrementing them wouldn't make sense.